# Obtain User Access Metrics in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Good morning;

I'd like to know if it's possible to make a query in Azure DevOps for obtaining the team's users accesses stats.
I can obtain the cards modified by the users, but i want to know if there's a way to know if the users are accessing to the boards (using Azure devops queries).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean to get users list who are accessing boards?

If so, I am afraid that there is **no** way to get this information right now.

This feature is not supported by azure devops for the time being.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response.

As you said, I need the list of the users who are accessing boards.

By the moment, I'll obtain the number of cards modified by each user, and this could give me an idea about the users activity.